# In pygame how to make an object controlled with arrow keys not move of the edge of the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I have made an object controlled with arrow keys. When I move it to the edge of the pygame screen, the object moves off the screen. I was wondering how to keep the object on the screen. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

On each handle of the input, check if the object's target x position plus its width exceeds the width of the canvas or if it is less than `0`. Deny the movement if so.

Repeat for the y coordinate and the height.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
if player.x == #edge of screen:
    player.x -= 0
if player.y == #edge of screen:
    player.y -= 0
```

`player.x` being the players current x position and `player.y` being the players current y position or you can do the same thing but when the player goes of the screen it automatically goes to the other side of the screen it will probably take some tweaking to get it to look perfect

Answer (score 0):

```
last = player.rect.copy()
player.update()
if not screen.get_rect().contains(player.rect):
    player.rect = last
```